# Dockerfile - “Host key verification failed…” error

Tags: git, docker

I've got this error when the Build is trying to clone the private repo:

> Cloning into '.'... Host key verification failed.
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Here is the build command:

> docker build --tag myimage --build-arg ssh_prv_key="$(cat
> ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" --build-arg ssh_pub_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" .

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM tarampampam/node:13-alpine

ARG ssh_prv_key
ARG ssh_pub_key

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/

RUN adduser "container" -D -h "/home/container"

RUN echo "$ssh_prv_key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    echo "$ssh_pub_key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

RUN  echo "    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config

RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN echo -e "Host github.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
RUN ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

USER container
ENV  USER container
ENV  HOME /home/container

RUN cd /home/container && git clone git@github.com:myPrivateRepo .

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -    && apt update     && apt -y upgrade     && apt -y install nodejs node-gyp     && apt -y install ffmpeg     && npm install discord.js node-opus opusscript     && npm install >


WORKDIR /home/container
```

I've checked, both /root/.ssh/id_rsa and /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub have the good key inside.

I've tried many options like ssh-keygen -R github.com

Comment: were you able to figure out the solution for this error ?

Comment: why do you need to run git clone inside the container build ?  You can just copy over to the container from the host with "https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy" . It would make your Dockerfiles cleaner

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you set up the ssh environment for the root user, then switch to user container (where the ssh config is not present) and then try to access github.  Generate the ssh configuration in ~container/.ssh.

Edit: One side note, using the above approach, you do share your private key as part of the image, so be careful who you give that image to.  Deleting the key will later on in the Dockerfile will not remove it from the image as each command you invoke creates a new layer that stores the delta to the previous image.  With the appropriate tools, I can inspect lower layers in the image and get hold of your private key even if deleted later on.

Comment: I was able to solve it by saving ssh to user's home directory. 

```bash
RUN echo "$ssh_prv_key" > /home/$USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    echo "$ssh_pub_key" > /home/$USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    chmod 600 /home/$USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 /home/$USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    chown -R $USERNAME:$USERNAME /home/$USERNAME/.ssh
```

Comment: Great to see that the answer helped you in solving the problem.  Replacing container with $USERNAME and keeping it generic is definitely a good idea.  Also see my note that I am adding to my original answer.